# box not getting shown

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place my bubble(blob) into a box with a red border and 500 pixels in size but unable to do so, please help me understand where my red box has been misplaced in the style sheet

```css
.box {
  border: 500px red;
}

.blob {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 58% 43% 33% 64%/50% 38% 53% 50%;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 6px 33px 20px 0px #800080, inset 20px 80px 15px 0px #Ffff00, 10px 20px 20px 0px #c9c9c9;
}

.blob::before {
  content: 'abc';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 37% 54% 46% 46%;
  background: white;
  width: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  height: 15px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.blob::after {
  content: 'def';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="blob"></div>
</div>
```

credit:@NanouuSymeon(twitter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your border property is missing solid like so:

```
border: 500px solid red;
```

However, with a border this thick, your bubble is engulfed. The below snippet shows with a border of 1px

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.blob {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 58% 43% 33% 64%/50% 38% 53% 50%;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 6px 33px 20px 0px #800080, inset 20px 80px 15px 0px #Ffff00, 10px 20px 20px 0px #c9c9c9;
}

.blob::before {
  content: 'abc';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 37% 54% 46% 46%;
  background: white;
  width: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  height: 15px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.blob::after {
  content: 'def';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="blob"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: great ..got your point

Comment: Glad you got sorted!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear: "box with 500px size": 500px what –  width, height? In my snippet below I set it to 500px width *and* height and defined the red border solid and 1px wide.  Adopt that to your needs...

To center the contents inside it, you can add flex-settings as done below. In that case, also add `position: relative;` to `.blob` to make it the position reference for your absolutely positioned pseudo-elements.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.blob {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 58% 43% 33% 64%/50% 38% 53% 50%;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 6px 33px 20px 0px #800080, inset 20px 80px 15px 0px #Ffff00, 10px 20px 20px 0px #c9c9c9;
  position: relative;
}

.blob::before {
  content: 'abc';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 37% 54% 46% 46%;
  background: white;
  width: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  height: 15px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.blob::after {
  content: 'def';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="blob"></div>
</div>
```